# write this xml in c#

Tags: c#, xml

What's the best way to produce this xml programmatically and persist to file? The data source is just going to be a csv file (you may suggest the csv file be formed another way if it makes programming the xml easier (flexible in this area)):

```
business name, address line
Comapny Name 1, 123 Main St.
Company Name 2, 1 Elm St.
Company Name 2, 2 Eml St.

<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<ArrayOfBusiness xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"> 
  <Business> 
    <Name>Company Name 1</Name> 
    <AddressList> 
      <Address> 
        <AddressLine>123 Main St.</AddressLine> 
      </Address> 
    </AddressList> 
  </Business> 
  <Business> 
    <Name>Company Name 2</Name> 
    <AddressList> 
      <Address> 
        <AddressLine>1 Elm St.</AddressLine> 
      </Address> 
      <Address> 
        <AddressLine>2 Elm St.</AddressLine> 
      </Address> 
    </AddressList> 
  </Business> 
</ArrayOfBusiness>
```

Comment: I would need more details about the context of your question.  Do you mean how to write it to the hard drive?  Do you mean how to create XML from a DB or IENumerable?

Comment: I would like to write it to file. And the data source can be a list<t>.

Comment: Are you going to be using your <t> in Web Services or WCF?

Comment: correction to data source. see updated op. my apologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand now that you are simply trying to convert the CSV file to the (inferred) XML schema above.

To follow on from the reply from Jason, this should accomplish most of it for you and act as starter code:

```
    internal string Convert()
    {
        string[] lines = {
                             "Company Name 1, 123 Main St.",
                             "Company Name 2, 1 Elm St.",
                             "Company Name 2, 2 Elm St"
                         };

        //var lines = File.ReadLines(path);
        var builder = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (var line in lines)
        {
            var fields = line.Split(',');

            var settings = new XmlWriterSettings {OmitXmlDeclaration = true};
            using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(builder, settings))
            {

                //writer.WriteStartDocument();

                writer.WriteStartElement("ArrayofBusiness");
                writer.WriteStartElement("Business");
                writer.WriteElementString("Name", fields[0]);
                writer.WriteStartElement("AddressList");
                writer.WriteStartElement("Address");
                writer.WriteElementString("AddressLine", fields[1]);

                writer.WriteEndElement();//Address
                writer.WriteEndElement();//AddressList
                writer.WriteEndElement();//Business
                writer.WriteEndElement();//ArrayOfBusiness

                //writer.WriteEndDocument();
            }
        }

        return builder.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: How do you make it where each element is on its own line and indented?

Comment: This will happen when you open the xml file in an xml reader.  Drop it into IE and it will indent.  I don't think the indentation is important only the data. XmlWriterSettings may have indentation settings.  I'll check when I get to a PC

Answer (score 4):

```
string path = @"C:\Path\To\Output.xml";
List<Business> list = // set data 

using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(new FileStream(path, FileMode.Write)))
{
  using (var xmlWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(streamWriter))
  {
    var serialiser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Business>));
    serialiser.Serialize(xmlWriter, list);
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for insightful answer, i've changed the data source to a csv file, i apologize for the update.

Comment: @rod: Come on, reading the CSV file into a list of `Business` is the trivial part (and the source is irrelevant for the question that you posed).

Comment: so do you mean xml can be skipped altogether? I'm sorry I'm not following.

Comment: What do you need the xml for? Is there a reason you need to persist it to a file?

Comment: Well, I figured the only way to take tabular data (spreadsheet/csv) and move it into my c# collection object is to covert to xml and deserialize into collection. Is there a more straightforward way?

Comment: @rod: `var list = new List<Business>(); var lines = File.ReadLines(path); foreach(var line in lines) { string[] fields = line.Split(','); string businessName = field[0]; string addressLine = field[1]; Business business = new Business(businessName, addressLine); list.Add(business); }` Of course I made some assumptions but you get the point. (I don't know if this compiles as I coded this on the fly in the comment box but it's going to be close enough.)

Comment: Watch out for fields that contain embedded commas. line.Split won't handle those properly.

Comment: @poke: That's contained in the pithy "[o]f course I made some assumptions but you get the point." I assumed, for example, that no field contains an embedded comma.

Comment: @Jason: I wondered if that was one of your assumptions but I figured it was worth pointing out if rod decides to go this route.

Answer (score 0):

I can understand the difficulty in answering this question.  There are many ways to recreate the xml but each technique has a pro and con depending on the system

for example:

- you could iterate the list and use the c# xml commands
- you could add xml attributes to your classes and properties and push them through a   serialiser
- you could even spit the xml out directly from sql

On top of that we have to assume that the elements shown are all the elements available as you have not provided a schema.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment, it looks like your question is actually about how to read, say, a CSV file and obtain a collection of `Business` objects based on the file.

I'll assume a `Business` class defined as follows:

```
class Business {
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine { get; set; }

    public Business(string companyName, string addressLine) {
        this.CompanyName = companyName;
        this.AddressLine = addressLine; 
    }
}
```

Then:

```
var businesses = new List<Business>();
var lines = File.ReadLines(path);
foreach(var line in lines) {
    string[] fields = line.Split(',');
    string companyName = fields[0];
    string addressLine = fields[1];
    Business business = new Business(companyName, addressLine);
    businesses.Add(business);
}
```

Note that I'm assuming that no field contains an embedded comma.